# How to highlight 80 columns when it contains a single % at the start

Tags: highlighting, column

How can I highlight 80 columns when a line has a single % at the very start? What I am looking for is that lines with a single % stand out by a colored rectangle 1 character high and 80 columns wide.

Comment: Are the 80 columns crucial for the application or is it okay if the whole line is highlighted? Highlighting the whole line is very simple: `M-x highlight-regexp` `^%` `<Ctrl-J>` `<RET>` and choose your favorite face.

Comment: @Tobias Yes, I am looking for a font-locking solution that highlights the entire line. I am able to highlight just the % with font-locking but don't know how to select the rest of the empty line.

Comment: The `<Ctrl-J>` in my former comment stands for the key combination: pressing J while holding the Control key down. This key combination inserts a newline when you input regexps. If you include that newline into your regexp the whole line is highlighted as you wish.

Comment: @Tobias Thank you! I currently have

      (add-hook 'markdown-mode-hook
                (lambda() (highlight-regexp "^%\n" 'hi-yellow)))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the major mode works with `font-lock-mode` you can add a font-lock keyword in the major mode hook.

If you include newlines in the match the line is highlighted over the full width of the window (if that is what you actually want).

The following example does that for lines only consisting of a single percent character in `LaTeX-mode` buffers:

```el
(defcustom my-empty-comment-face 'hi-yellow
  "Face for highlighting empty comment lines."
  :type 'facep
  :group 'LaTeX)

(defun my-font-lock-empty-comments ()
  "Highlight empty comments in `LaTeX-mode'."
  (message "Adding my-empty-comment-face")
  (font-lock-add-keywords
   nil
   '((
      "^%\n" ;; matcher
      . ;; match-highlight:
      (0 ;; subexp
       `(face ,my-empty-comment-face) ;;< facename (evaluates to (face FACE PROP1 VAL1 ...)
       t ;;< override comment face
       ))))))

(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook #'my-font-lock-empty-comments)
```

---

Even if the text above is what you actually want I will also answer your question more directly.

Instead of highlighting the whole line you asked for highlighting 80 characters of it:

> How to highlight **80 columns** when it contains a single % at the start

From those 80 characters 79 characters — the space characters behind the percent sign — do not even exist.

Therefore we put a `display` property with the highlighted string of the right length on the existing percent sign.

There follows the modified code:

```el
(defcustom my-empty-comment-face 'hi-yellow
  "Face for highlighting empty comment lines."
  :type 'facep
  :group 'LaTeX)

(defun my-font-lock-empty-comments ()
  "Highlight empty comments in `LaTeX-mode'."
  (message "Adding my-empty-comment-face")
  (font-lock-add-keywords
   nil
   '((
      "^%\n" ;; matcher
      . ;; match-highlight:
      (0 ;; subexp
       `(face default display ,(propertize (concat "%" (make-string 79 ?\s))  'face my-empty-comment-face)) ;;< facename (evaluates to (face FACE PROP1 VAL1 ...)
       t ;;< override comment face
       ))))))

(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook #'my-font-lock-empty-comments)
```